# Confusion with $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I was reading Physics from Symmetry from Jakop Schwichtenberg and I got confused by the definitions of groups $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$.

As far as I understood, unit complex numbers with the ordinary multiplication forms a group and it is called $U(1)$. $U$ for its being unitary ($U^*U =1$) and $1$ for its being represented by single complex numbers.

Moreover, in the book he defines
\begin{align}
1 =& \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
&i = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and shows that we end up with the same results as $SO(2)$.

On the other hand, just like unit complex numbers, unit quaternions also form a group with ordinary multiplication. At this point he defines

\begin{align}\label{asd}
&1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
&i = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
&j = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & i \\
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
&k = \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 \\
0 & -i 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and called this $SU(2)$, S denotes $det(U)=1$  and $U$ denotes $U^\dagger U=1$ and 2 denotes $2\times 2$ matrices.

So, the question is:
By the same logic we called unit complex numbers $U(1)$, shouldn't we say unit quaternions also $U(1)$, since they both unitary and represented by single number.

Also, By the same logic we called $SU(2)$ to matrix representation of the unit quaternions, shouldn't we also say that matrix representation of unit complex numbers are $SU(2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are technically correct, but obviously this would cause a lot of confusion if you call the quaternion unitary group $U(1)$ as well. Note that if you say "represented by a single number", it matters if you mean real, complex or quaternion numbers. Therefore, the quaternion unitary group is usually denoted $U(1,\mathbb{H})$ or $Sp(1)$. As you correctly observed, it holds $SO(2) \cong U(1)$ and $SU(2) \cong U(1,\mathbb{H})$.

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a simple answer. I thought I was missing something. Thanks a lot.